# Multiple type assertions in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I was looking at the source code of an angular repository and stumbled upon a line of code that uses multiple type assertions.

The code looks kinda like this one, it uses 2 type assertion: `unknown` and `Record<string, unknown>`

```
 (window as unknown as Record<string, unknown>)['ResizeObserver']
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/IKatsuba/angular-three/blob/7d5474a640c438cf3585fb8f3ef2062caec1263b/libs/core/src/lib/di/resize.ts) to the actual file.

What does multiple assertions actually mean?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You use type assertions too narrow down the type of a value so you can use it.  This is known as [double assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion).

> The assertion from type S to T succeeds if either S is a subtype of T or T is a subtype of S.

Since we are unsure of the shape of the `window` object we cannot be sure that we can check that the `ResizeObserver` property has a value other than null.

So we can cast it to unknown, because anything can be assigned to unknown.

And because anything can be assigned to unknown we now have free range to shape the object how we want in order to satisfy our conditional. Since we need to check that a properties value is not null, we can simply use `Record<string, unknown>`

We end up with:

```
(window as unknown as Record<string, unknown>)['ResizeObserver'] != null
```

By doing this we can write a conditional to check that the `ResizeObserver` property is not null no matter what shape the `window` object has.

Comment: Awesome, got it. Thanks for the link to an article.

Answer (score 8):

You can think of `as` like an operator (left associative):

```
((window as unknown) as Record<string, unknown>)['ResizeObserver']
```

So here, it casts window to `unknown` which is valid. It's upcasting from the type of `window` to `unknown`.

Then we downcast from `unknown` to `Record<string, unknown>`, which is also perfectly valid.

But if we do only `window as Record<string, unknown>`, we get an error. Window does not have anything in common with `Record<string, unknown>`!

Here's an extra example of `as` to demonstrate that it's just a simple operator:

```
42 as number as number as number

(((42 as number) as number) as number)
```

You can think of it like this:

```
VALID
       unknown
         ^ \
        /   \
Window /     > Record<string, unknown>
```

```
INVALID
Window ------> Record<string, unknown>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This helped me clear my remaining confusion about this topic. Although the term upcast and downcast are pretty new to me. Any reference to such terms?

It seems to me, based on the visuals you provided here, i can view it like a wave in the way the direction moves everytime we typecast