# Typesript typing an array of objects of unknown shape

Tags: arrays, typescript, types, record

I am trying to construct a type for row in table. All I know is that keys must be string, and key values must be string or number or boolean. I have this:

```
type Row = Record<string, number | string | boolean>;

interface User {
    name: string
}

const objArr: User[] = [
    {name: 'John'},
    {name: 'Jack'}
]

const testArr: Row[] = objArr
```

But there is an error:

```
Type 'User[]' is not assignable to type 'Row[]'.
  Type 'User' is not assignable to type 'Row'.
    Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'User'.(2322)
```

I am not sure how to construct a type for object of unknown shape...

Answer (score 0):

It would be better for you to completely know what sort of data you're dealing with, otherwise you lose the benefits of having TypeScript altogether.

**With that said**, you could do something like the following:

```js
interface User {
  name: string
}

type Row = User & Record<string, number | string | boolean>;

const objArr: Row[] = [
    {name: 'John'},
    {name: 'Jack'}
]

const testArr: Row[] = objArr 

const someVar= testArr[0]["something"]
// type of someVar: number | string | boolean
```

What you have here is type extension, where `Row` contains `User` data, as well as other possible entries.

###### Drawback

If you go down this route however, it may be wise to also use `Partial` with the `Record` keyword, as you cannot guarantee that any given key will exist... (or have a value)

```js
interface User {
  name: string
}

type Row = User & Partial<Record<string, number | string | boolean>>;

const objArr: Row[] = [
    {name: 'John'},
    {name: 'Jack'}
]

const testArr: Row[] = objArr 

const someVar= testArr[0]["something"]
// type of someVar: number | string | boolean | undefined
```

Comment: This is type is for generic row, all I know is that keys are strings, and a key value could be string or boolean or number

Answer (score -1):

Consider using an assertion here:

```
type Row = Record<string, number | string | boolean>;

interface User {
    name: string
}

const objArr: User[] = [
    {name: 'John'},
    {name: 'Jack'}
]

const testArr = objArr as unknown as Row[]
```

TypeScript dislikes this assignment since `Row` has an index signature while `User` doesn't. This would mean that you could use any key with `Row`, but not with `User`, hence the error.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXqMQN)

Comment: I have tried assertion, but the error remains

Comment: @momi Mistake on my part. This kind of upcasting needs a cast to `unknown` first. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71190622/multiple-type-assertions-in-typescript) for why and what it does.