# Understanding `as unknown as` in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react codebase where `as unknown as` is being multiple time while defining a variable. Some of the examples are as follows:

1. `const [id, setId] = React.useState(null as unknown as string)`;
2. `const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = React.useState(null as unknown as any)`;
3. `const [generateRequest, setGenerateRequest] = React.useState(null as unknown as GenerateRequest)`;

I understand the use of `null as string` but `null as unknown as string` doesn't make much sense to me. Can anyone please help me understand the same? What is the use-case and how does it actually help?

Thanks.

Comment: [Double assertion in Typescript](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/71190622/18244921

Answer (score 2):

This is a [double assertion](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/type-assertion#double-assertion). `x as unknown as y` allows you to pretend a value is of a type, even if the compiler knows it's really not. It's more or less the same as `any` in terms of safety, but provides more information in the type signature.

Comment: yeah but the question is why do we require such double assertions? What is the use case for the same?

Comment: They're required when you want to tell the compiler "Trust me, I really do want to use this type for this identifer." Typecasting to `unknown` allows you to then cast to any other type. This gives you the benefit of having a useful type for that identifier (better for readability than just using `any` or `unknown`, and allowing TypeScript to check using the right-hand type in the assertion) in situations where the compiler would usually disagree with the programmer. In addition to the other links, the explanation [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28067) might help.